# How to catch fractions as an entity?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have sample sentences like

> What is 1 third of 9
>
> what is 2/5 of twenty

I can catch the number easily in the end. But there doesn't seem to be a system entity for fractions. Should I make my own? And am I right that I would need to write out every variation of every fraction I want to support?

Answer (score 0):

there is no system entity for this. No.

But you can try your luck with [composite entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities#developer_composite).

With them you could create an entity which represents something like this:

- "`@sys.number` divided by `@sys.number`" for "two divided by five"
- "`@sys.number` `@sys.ordinal`" for "two fifths"

I am not sure if Dialogflow understands "half" or "quarter", so maybe you have to add them as well. But then you can then use them in a composite entity like above. Maybe you have to add "a" = 1 as well.

- "What is the half of twenty." => 1/2 * 20
- "What is a fifth of twenty." => 1/5 * 20
- "What is two quarters of twenty." => 2/4 * 20

Comment: Thank you for the great starting point. I have struggled to get a composite entity to recognise plural ordinals. I.e I cannot get it to recognise tenths or thirds

Comment: @Somk You can either add synonyms for tenths -> tenth, thirds -> third.
Or teach Dialogflow, that "tenths" is the ordinal "tenth".

I added tenths and thirds to an intent and told Dialogflow, that they are ordinals.